# WPF : Change DataTemplate of specific cell on DataGrid

Tags: wpf

I want to create a DataGrid like this :

[image]

User can add-remove columns at run-time. as shown in the picture I have to use DatePicker and checkbox and other controls on specific **Cells** . 
How can I do it using WPF DataGrid ?

I think I have to change DataTemplate of particular cell but I don't know how

Is DataGrid appropriate control for this case ?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest putting all the filter controls(?) above the line below "suspended" in the header of the DataGrid. You can put in there whatever you want.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="MySpecialHeaderTemplate">
        ...
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <DataGrid>
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource MySpecialHeaderTemplate}"
                    Binding="{Binding ...}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource MySpecialHeaderTemplate}"
                    Binding="{Binding ...}" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

This is not easy, especially finding the ViewModel holding the data of those controls in the header, but it is possible.